# When to use imap_qprint?

Tags: php, email, imap, pop3

I'm using PHP's [IMAP Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php) extension to check e-mail from a POP3 account.

When it comes to actually fetching the message, I have the following code:

```
// Make new raw email message
// With PHP Imap, we need to fetch headers and body separately!
$body = imap_fetchheader($mailbox, $msgno);
$body .= imap_qprint(imap_body($mailbox, $msgno));
```

All the examples I am able to find mentions that one should use [imap_qprint()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-qprint.php) here, but I've noticed that when I do all the GET parameters of a URI get mangled.

For example,

`http://localhost/pronk.php?id=6248&amp;key=c7eb7c5173e1525a47c63abc39d938e1`

becomes:

`http://localhost/pronk.php?idb48&amp;keyÇeb7c5173e1525a47c63abc39d938e1`

If I *don't* use `imap_qprint()` everything seems to work just fine. (I'm using `imap_body` instead of `imap_fetch_body` because I want the entire e-mail - headers, parts, and everything) But since all examples I can find say to use qprint, I wanted to know why my code seems to need it omitted?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still curious about this, but if you do want to use imap_qprint(), you need to first check what the encoding of the message is.

You can do this using imap_fetchstructure(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php.

Only if the encoding is set to 'QUOTED-PRINTABLE' would you want to use imap_qprint().